# Centered, boxed math(s) equations

Tags: html, css, mathml

I'm trying to make centered, boxed math(s) equations using MathML as part of HTML5. The problem is the boxes. If I put a border on my div element, the border is tall enough, but it extends all the way to the left and right sides of the screen. If I put a border on my math element, it is the right width, but isn't tall enough for the elements inside the multiline table.

```
<div align="center" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
  <math style="border: 1px solid #000;"><mi>x</mi><mfenced open="{" close=""><mtable>
    <mtr><mtd><mtext>row 1</mtext></td></mtr>
    <mtr><mtd><mtext>row 2</mtext></td></mtr>
  </mtable></mfenced></math>
</div>
```

Why do the elements have such strange sizes? Shouldn't they both be the size of their contents? How can I create a box just big enough to contain the text, without giving any element an explicit size?

(Apologies for the lack of an image. I uploaded one, but I don't have the proper reputation to post it.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div>` is a block element, hence it will fill the complete width of the current parent box. You could just set it to use `display: inline-block;` to fit the width of its content:

```
<div align="center" style="border: 1px solid #000; display: inline-block;">
  <math><mi>x</mi><mfenced open="{" close=""><mtable>
    <mtr><mtd><mtext>row 1</mtext></mtd></mtr>
    <mtr><mtd><mtext>row 2</mtext></mtd></mtr>
  </mtable></mfenced></math>
</div>
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ubfn5t2x/1/)

---

Besides, in your code you use `</td>` instead of `</mtd>`.

Comment: Thank you! That works. (I'll accept the answer when it lets me, in a few minutes.)

Do you know why the height of the math element doesn't encompass all its contents?

Comment: No, but from a first glance I think, this is a bug.

Comment: What browser and version are you using? The fiddle's border height looks ok to me in Firefox 37.0.2 and Safari 7.1.5, both on Mac OS 10.9.5.

Comment: @DaveBarton I think OP is referring to his approach and not my solution. Have you checked Op's code?

Comment: You're right, the OP's code shows a bug in Firefox. I encourage him to report it.

Answer (score 0):

is a block element so it covers the whole width of the page. You can set its display property in CSS to inline then it will work as you want. may be you need an extra  element to cover the inner one.

```
display: inline;
```